# It gives an error when I try to call .format(member.mention) discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Can anyone help? The fact is that I am a novice developer and I can't understand why I get this error in the console. discord.ext .commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Embed.add_field() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'value'. I seem to be doing everything right.

Here is the code I use:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Ban')

    emb.add_field(name = 'Ban',  value = 'Baned user {}'.format(member.mention))
    emb.set_author(name = ctx.author.display_name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar)

    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Comment: How do you add the member parameter? When you type your command, do you tag the user?

Answer (score 0):

For Adding Fields To Embeds, Do Like This :

`emb.add_field(name="Field1", value="say Hi", inline=False)`

And Use `F Strings` Like : `value = f"Banned User : {member.mention}"`
For Better **Performance** !

[More Info](https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/10/send-embed-discord-py-with-code-examples.html)